# When a tab is selected, how do I refresh the entire app (f5)?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a shiny app that has 4 tabs, with each tab allowing the end user to select something from with a table. Basically I want the end user to go through each of the tabs, but whenever they select the 1st tab, I want the app to reset (equivalent to hitting F5).

I have the following code:

```
ui = fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                helpText("Model: "),
                textOutput("selectedmodel"),
                helpText("issue: "),
                textOutput("selectissue")
                
                tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                            tabPanel(value="modelselection","Model Selection", fluid=TRUE, 
                                     sidebarLayout(
                                       sidebarPanel(tags$a("Select a row", href=("Additional Text"))),
                                       mainPanel(
                                         DT::dataTableOutput('modelselectiontable')
                                       ))),
                            tabPanel(value = "issue"...
```

And I continue building tabs in the UI. Then in the server section:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$tabs, {
       
    if(input$tabs == "modelselection"){
      session$reload()
      print("Model TAB Selected")
      output$selectissue<-renderText("")    
    }
```

The `session$reload()` does refresh shiny, but it does it constantly.

Is there a way to only allow the `session$reload()` to load just once when that first tab is activated? Or is there a way to refresh only when the first tab is clicked?

Thank you for help, this is my first time working in shiny, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try giving a specific id to your `tabPanel`?  `tabPanel (id="myid" , ....)` Then you may call this id in `observeEvent(input$myid,....) ` . I am not sure if it solves the issue but It's worth to try.

Comment: @maydin Simple solution, that seemed to work. Thank you

Comment: If it solves the issue I will add this as an answer to close the question?